# How to use class variable condition in unittest mock python

Tags: python-2.7

```
class player(self, args):
   self.name = args.name
   self.hobby = 'cricket'
   ....

def xyz(self):
   if self.hobby == 'cricket':
       statement 1
       ...
```

My problem is how to use if self.hobby =='cricket' variable condition in my unit test mock, mean how do i create this variable condition in my unit test function

Comment: You don't necessarily need a mock here. You can manipulate the truth of he condition by changing the value of `hobby` after you create the instanced, but before you call `xyz`.  For example, `p = player("bob"); p.hobby = "football"; p.xyz()`.

Comment: @chepner hi, thanks but actually I want to create a unit test for Xyz function, So there is one if condition like this if self.hobby == 'cricket' , My confusion is to how to use this condition in my test scenario.

Comment: Just as I said: you control the result of the comparison when you call the method by controlling the value of `self.hobby`.

Comment: please correct me where i am wrong, 

Ex:
 @mock.patch('player.xyz')
 def test_xyz(self, mock_player_xyz):
    mock.player_xyz.return_value = None
 " what should i include here to add those if conditions of class variable "
    self.assertIsNone(player.xyz())

Comment: There is a lot to fix in your code before you can get that far. However, you aren't using the condition at all, and in fact you aren't testing anything useful. All you are doing is confirming that the mock, when called, returns the value you said it should return.

Comment: @chepner ok thanks, actually this is just a dummy code for my project to understand the query :)